# Combining two python dicts with tuple by multiplication - Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two dicts:

```
d2 = {'dog': 1.0, 'bird': 0.0, 'egret': 2.0, 'aardvark': 1.0, 'cat': 3.0, 'fish': 2.0}

d1 = {1: [('dog', 3), ('bird', 1)], 2: [('egret', 1), ('aardvark', 1), ('cat', 1), ('bird', 2)], 3: [('dog', 1), ('aardvark', 5), ('fish', 3), ('bird', 1)], 4: [('dog', 1), ('aardvark', 2), ('fish', 3), ('bird', 1)], 5: [('egret', 2), ('bird', 1)], 6: [('bird', 1)], 7: [('dog', 5), ('bird', 6)], 8: [('aardvark', 1), ('bird', 8)]}
```

What I need to accomplish is, for every tuple, look up the first value of the tuple in `d1` and multiply the second value by the value in `d1`. So `d2` should ultimately look like:

```
d3 = {1: [('dog', 3), ('bird', 0)], 2: [('egret', 2), ('aardvark', 1), ('cat', 3), ('bird', 0)], 3: [('dog', 1), ('aardvark', 5), ('fish', 6), ('bird', 0)], 4: [('dog', 1), ('aardvark', 2), ('fish', 6), ('bird', 0)], 5: [('egret', 4), ('bird', 0)], 6: [('bird', 0)], 7: [('dog', 5), ('bird', 0)], 8: [('aardvark', 1), ('bird', 0)]}
```

I have tried to accomplish this:

```
for key, val in d1.items():
    currVal = val[0][0]
    num = [val for k, v in d2.items() if key == currVal]
    multiplier = num[0]
    val[0][1] = val[0][1] * multiplier
```

But I am getting `IndexError: list index out of range` which I think is because I am accessing the dicts incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
d2 = {'dog': 1.0, 'bird': 0.0, 'egret': 2.0, 'aardvark': 1.0, 'cat': 3.0, 'fish': 2.0}
d1 = {1: [('dog', 3), ('bird', 1)], 2: [('egret', 1), ('aardvark', 1), ('cat', 1), ('bird', 2)], 3: [('dog', 1), ('aardvark', 5), ('fish', 3), ('bird', 1)], 4: [('dog', 1), ('aardvark', 2), ('fish', 3), ('bird', 1)], 5: [('egret', 2), ('bird', 1)], 6: [('bird', 1)], 7: [('dog', 5), ('bird', 6)], 8: [('aardvark', 1), ('bird', 8)]}
new_d = {a:[(c, int(d2[c]*d)) for c, d in b] for a, b in d1.items()}
```

Output:

```
{1: [('dog', 3), ('bird', 0)], 2: [('egret', 2), ('aardvark', 1), ('cat', 3), ('bird', 0)], 3: [('dog', 1), ('aardvark', 5), ('fish', 6), ('bird', 0)], 4: [('dog', 1), ('aardvark', 2), ('fish', 6), ('bird', 0)], 5: [('egret', 4), ('bird', 0)], 6: [('bird', 0)], 7: [('dog', 5), ('bird', 0)], 8: [('aardvark', 1), ('bird', 0)]}
```